# How do I know whether my Debian is being hacked/infected?

Tags: security, debian, debian-squeeze

My laptop seems to be acting rather weird - saying that another person is logged in when I try to shut it down (or maybe it likes being turned on).

So how do I know whether my Debian laptop is being hacked or not?

Are there some kind of general guidelines for checking?

Comment: unplug the network cable. if you still get the same message, then it's a problem with the comp, not a hacker

Comment: you probably had logged in as a root in the terminal and closed the terminal window without logging out

Comment: So what does it really do? Can you be a bit more specific (e.g. what does it say *exactly*)?

Answer (score 4):

Inspect your `auth.log`:

```
sudo less /var/log/auth.log
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run `w` and `who` commands on the command line to see what is being run and who is connected to your machine. Additionally, you can use `netstat -a` to see active internet connections.

If you find users you don't recognized connecting to/from unknown addresses/sites then you may want to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

well, it seems that I was a bit paranoid :)

I also found chkrootkit and its howto at:
http://www.howtoforge.com/scan_linux_for_rootkits

anyway, thanks for all these answers!